# sublime text 3 сложная замена текста

Tags: sublime-text-3, замена-текста

нужно выполнить такую замену:

```
строка 1
строка 2


строка 3

строка 4
```

-->

```
<p>строка 1</p>
<p>строка 2</p>
<p>строка 3</p>
<p>строка 4</p>
```

можно ли сделать это в окне найти/заменить? можно ли написать какой то скрипт? ST3 поддерживает скрипты?

Comment: Регулярки в помощь `^(.+?)(\n+|$)` → `<p>\1</p>\n`

Answer (score 0):

Элементарно, в три приема, без никаких регулярок:

1. Двойные переносы меняете на одинарные (несколько раз, если есть тройные и более)
2. Переносы меняете на `</p>перенос<p>`
3. Корректируете начало и конец